# jQuery binding to an element by id

Tags: jquery, keyboard

What I'm trying to do is that when the <kbd>esc</kbd> key is pressed on the text 
input field (id = txtSearch), some code will run.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#txtSearch').bind('keyup', function(e) { 
        var characterCode; // literal character code will be stored in this variable 
        if (e && e.which) { //if which property of event object is supported (NN4) 
            e = e; 
            characterCode = e.which; 
        } else { 
            characterCode = e.keyCode; 
        } 
        if (characterCode == 27)  //if esc key
        { 
            //do stuff 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

It doesnt work for me. However, if I would change that line:

```
$('#txtSearch').bind('keyup', function(e) {
```

with:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
```

everything works. But I don't want to bind the keyup with <kbd>esc</kbd> to the 
whole document...

Any suggestions on how I can bind the the keyup only with the specific 
text search element? (or its containing div or something)

Thanks!

Comment: What you have should work.  You might examine `$('#txtSearch').length` to see if that selector is matching any elements.

Comment: Are you working with asp.net?  It mangles element ids, so you may want to use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$('input#txtSearch').bind('keyup', function(e) {
```

is the line you are looking for.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your html has an element with id txtSearch.

If you are using ASP.NET, you'll have to change

```
$('#txtSearch').bind('keyup', function(e) {
```

to

```
$('#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').bind('keyup', function(e) {
```

so that jQuery gets the full generated id.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('input').keydown(function(e){ 
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
            $(this).parents('form').submit(); 
             return false; 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or what about using :

```
$('input[id=txtSearch]').bind('keyup', function(e) {
```

Just a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I gave that up. I cant seem to find a way to attach this event only to a specific element of the **DOM**.

So, this is my work around:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "txtSearch") {
        var characterCode; // literal character code will be stored in this variable
        if (e && e.which) { //if which property of event object is supported (NN4)
            e = e;
            characterCode = e.which; //character code is contained in NN4's which property
        }
        else {
            characterCode = e.keyCode; //character code is contained in IE's keyCode property
        }

        if (characterCode == 27)  //if generated character code is equal to ascii 27 (if esc key)
        {
           //do stuff
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either check `$('#txtSearch').length` in a debugger or type

```
javascript:alert($('#txtSearch').length);
```

into your address bar to make sure it's actually selecting an element. If not, you could try adding a css class to your textbox and using `$('.txtSearch')`.